# Was Aaron a high priest of the natural twelve tribes of Israel only?

Tags: exodus, moses, priestly

After Aaron had been chosen as the High Priest of Israel he is said to have worn a breastpiece with twelve precious stones which represented the natural twelve tribes of Israel

Exodus 28:15

> “Fashion a breastpiece for making decisions—the work of skilled hands. Make it like the ephod: of gold, and of blue, purple and scarlet yarn, and of finely twisted linen. 16 It is to be square—a span[a] long and a span wide—and folded double. 17 Then mount four rows of precious stones on it. The first row shall be carnelian, chrysolite and beryl; 18 the second row shall be turquoise, lapis lazuli and emerald; 19 the third row shall be jacinth, agate and amethyst; 20 the fourth row shall be topaz, onyx and jasper.[b] Mount them in gold filigree settings. 21 ***There are to be twelve stones, one for each of the names of the sons of Israel***, each engraved like a seal with the name of one of the twelve tribes.

Since the twelve stones are said to represent each tribe of Israel does this stand to reason that Aaron's intercession was only for the children of Israel

Was Aaron a high priest of the natural twelve tribes only?

Comment: I'm not clear on what your question is.  What do you mean by "natural"?  Aaron was the high priest for the entire nation of Israel, for anyone of the twelve tribes as well as converts who joined the nation by choice.

Comment: @diyImma,by natural i mean literal israel and that Aaron represented only the Israelites and those who converted to judaism

Comment: As opposed to whom else?

Answer (score 1):

This will be very short.

Aaron was a levite and the high priest of Israel alone.  This is clear,  However, that role **represented** the coming Messiah as High Priest for all mankind as half the book of Hebrews is at pains to explain.  See Heb 4:14, 15, 5:1, 8:1, etc.

Comment: Perhaps "introduced" the role, more than represented? There's a sense in which the whole nation of Israel is priest to the other nations, and Jesus as true Israel is high priest for all people. The Levitical system taught and prepared us for Jesus, but I'm not sure it's right to say they represented/symbolised Jesus.